# Is there a way to save preferences for import/exporters?

Tags: export, customization

I often use the .fbx export plugin in Blender, and every time I must disable the apply scale and enable selected only options. I realise that not everyone wants these settings enabled by default, but is there a way to save the settings so that I never have to do it again?

Note: I can probably edit the script to change the default, but I have a strong feeling that it can be done and saved with my user prefs somehow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use operator presets. (Press the `+` icon to the right hand side of *Operator Presets* dropdown).

Comment: I've just realised, that since Blender updated and I lost my modified export script I need to use this preset answer to asve the exporter presets. However, the problem is that they are NOT applied by default and I have to actually select my preset. This is leaving me with the same problem as before. Is there a way to save a DEFAULT preset?

Comment: When you open a new version of Blender, it gives the option to copy old settings, This will copy your presets over too.

Comment: How do I make my operator preset the default option, so that I don't need to re-select it every time I close and re-open Blender?

Answer (score 5):

This is not the answer I want, but I'm going to post it anyway because it may be helpful to some.

Here is the method to do it by editing the script for anyone else that wants to change options. Note that because I'm editing a default addon directly, it will need to be done every time a new version of Blender comes out, which is why I'd like to know if there is a way to do this with preferences.

Find the **init**.py file for the FBX import/export plugin:
**<Blender install directory>\<version>\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx__init__.py**

In the ExportFBX class there are a number of properties, which all have **name** and **default** parameters. The name parameter is the text shown in the Blender UI, so you should be able to find the property you'd like to edit by searching for this string. Change the default parameter to that of your choosing. For example, to answer my question, I would change the default parameter of the property with name "*Selected Objects*" to True, and that of "*Apply Unit*" to False.

Answer (score 1):

There's two places these files might be.

1. In your Blender installation folder:
   `C:\<blender_install_path>\2.93\scripts\presets\operator\export_scene.fbx\`
2. A separate user settings folder on Windows for Blender:
   `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version>\scripts\presets\operator\export_scene.fbx\`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to overwrite the default export settings, in 3.5 you can edit `__init__.py` in:

> C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender
> 3.5\3.5\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx

Comment: This is the same as the other answer. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40240/30849 ?