# Set default fbx export settings

Tags: export

Does anyone know how to make Blender remember fbx export settings? Specifically Face Smoothing in the Geometry tab. It keeps defaulting to Normal but I need to to be Face:

[image]

Comment: Use the operator preset, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40237/is-there-a-way-to-save-preferences-for-import-exporters/40243

Comment: So that doesn't really answer the question, it says how to make an operator preset, but how do you make this the default?