# How to save export operator presets as a new default - ? No way short of scripting

Tags: customization

I have specific obj export settings as an operator preset, but they reset to default whenever I close Blender 2.78.

Can export operator settings be saved as a preference, so I don't have to manually apply the preset every time I open Blender?

Edit: Looks as if Blender cannot save specific Operator Presets to function as new default settings when Blender opens, except by working directly with the py script.

Apparently not too complicated, but seems a glaring kind of oversight, to be able to easily save User Preferences, but not obvious preferences like Import Export settings. That should be under User Preferences. To be able to remap the keyboard and save that, but not Operator presets? I don't see the logic behind that strategy.

Comment: "manually apply the preset " do you mean you are aware of saving presets of desired options in the Operator Presets dropdown in the export settings and don't want to use it?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40237/is-there-a-way-to-save-preferences-for-import-exporters

Comment: That's it, Mr Zak. I have a preset with the settings I use for most every session/project. I want that preset as the default when I open Blender, instead of having to change the existing default via the dropdown each time I work with Blender.